# Can't exchange authorization code for token on google oauth using php form

Tags: php, oauth

I can get the authorization code easily, but I keep getting errors when trying to exchange it for an access token.

```
    <FORM action="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth" method="post">

<input type = "hidden" name = "code" value = "4%2FXR0s9YvmROnHOpNUuiSlfxHE7xj-">    

<input type = "hidden" name = "redirect_uri" value = "http%3A%2F%2Fwww.m1448analytics.com%2Foauth2%2Frecv.php"> 

<input type = "hidden" name = "client_id" value = "502294831256-84q1ar05j14knsh5h2msvofu68e7rpaj.apps.googleusercontent.com">   

<input type = "hidden" name = "scope" value = "">   

<input type = "hidden" name = "client_secret" value = "hiding it">  

<input type = "hidden" name = "grant_type" value = "authorization_code">    

<INPUT type="submit" value="Send"> 

</FORM>
```

Google says: Error: invalid_request
Required parameter is missing: response_type
Learn more
Request Details

Comment: I'll go out on a limb and say you need to add `response_type`?

Comment: The ones who are viewing This Question. C2DM is deprecated please go and implement GCM for push notifications http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html

Answer (score 13):

The URL which you are requesting is:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
```

Which is the URL for obtaining the  Authentication code. Now if you want to obtain a token then the URL should be:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
```

Change this and your code should work.

Answer (score 4):

You're probably missing `response_type=code`

The `response_type` parameter determines if the Google OAuth 2.0 endpoint returns an authorization code. If you're writing an app on a web server, you should use `code`.

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer

Comment: FYI, I had to tack this onto the URL that the 'gsutil config' command generated for me. Searches for this error message weren't giving me anything specifically containing gsutil. Hopefully this gets indexed so other folks can find it more quickly in the future.